# UNIX END TIME January 19, 2038 - Will it affect Timelock nLOCKTIME smart contracts past that date?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, timestamp, locktime, hash-time-locked-contract

So UNIX END TIME is January 19, 2038.

- What will happen then to the btc TX that looks at Unixtime for nLOCKTIME transactions?
- Will any Locktime transaction past that date, say to 2040 be an issue? Or will blockchain continue adding to the Unix time like there was no end date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Timestamps in Bitcoin, including block timestamps and nLocktime values, are unsigned 32-bit.

The last possible timestamp is Feb 7th 2106, at 06:28:15 UTC.

Comment: That is good to hear that nLocktime will not be affected then. Thankyou